# Unit testing a code that uses Azure Cloud Services

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, unit-testing, azure-cloud-services

I have got a code for which I have to write unit tests.
Since I am new to unit tests, I am reaching out to your assistance.
I want to test the method IsAdmin, which gets as an input a CloudTableClient and a string, but I don't really know how to approach it.
I tried the code below, but it failed with the message:

> Message: Test method UnitTestMatan.UserControllerTests.IsAdmin_NotOnTheList_ReturnFalse threw exception: 
>   System.MethodAccessException: Attempt by method 'MatanWebServer.Controllers.UserController.IsAdmin(Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.CloudTableClient, System.String)' to access method 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.CloudTable.ExecuteQuery(Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableQuery, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableRequestOptions, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.OperationContext)' failed.

Basically, the first thing that I want to test is that IsAdmin will return false when it gets an email which is not in the table or just a random String.
In the test part, I want to use the table generated in UserController and not build a new one.

The following is the class I need to test:

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table;
using ParseMatanDataWebJob;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace MatanWebServer.Controllers
{    
    public class UserController : ApiController
    {
        // GET: api/user
        [AdminAuthorizeAttribute]
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=matandata;AccountKey=myconnectionstringthatidontwantyoutoknow");
            CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();

            IEnumerable<string> EmailsList = GetAllEmails(tableClient);

            return (EmailsList);
        }

        // GET: api/user/5
        [UserAuthorizeAttribute]        
        public ReturnObjectValuescontroller Get(string email)
        {            
            // Retrieve the storage account from the connection string.p
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("myconnectionstringthatidontwantyoutoknow");

            // Create the table client.
            CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();

            var result = new ReturnObjectValuescontroller();

            result.isAdmin = IsAdmin(tableClient, email);

            // Create the CloudTable object that represents the "people" table.
            CloudTable donationsTable = tableClient.GetTableReference("userdonationsdata");

            // Create the table query.
            TableQuery<DonationData> userDonationsQuery = new TableQuery<DonationData>().Where(
            TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, email.ToString()));

            var DonationsResult = donationsTable.ExecuteQuery(userDonationsQuery).ToList();

            result.DonationsList = DonationsResult;

            return result;
        }

        public static bool IsAdmin(CloudTableClient tableClient, string email)
        {
            CloudTable AdminsTable = tableClient.GetTableReference("matanadminusers");

            TableQuery AdminsListQuery = new TableQuery();

            AdminsListQuery.SelectColumns = new List<string>() { "AdminEmail" };

            var TableEntityAdminsList = AdminsTable.ExecuteQuery(AdminsListQuery).ToList();

            List<string> AdminsEmailList = new List<string>();
            foreach (var item in TableEntityAdminsList)
            {
                AdminsEmailList.Add(item.Properties["AdminEmail"].StringValue);
            }

            return (AdminsEmailList.Contains(email, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
        }

        private IEnumerable<string> GetAllEmails(CloudTableClient tableClient)
        {            
            CloudTable donationsTable = tableClient.GetTableReference("useremails");

            TableQuery EmailsListQuery = new TableQuery();

            EmailsListQuery.SelectColumns = new List<string>() { "RowKey" };

            var DynamicEntityEmailsList = donationsTable.ExecuteQuery(EmailsListQuery).ToList();

            List<string> EmailList = new List<string>();
            foreach (var item in DynamicEntityEmailsList)
            {
                EmailList.Add(item.RowKey);
            }
            return EmailList.Distinct();
        }

        // POST: api/Rony
        public void Post([FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

        // PUT: api/Rony/5
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

        // DELETE: api/Rony/5
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the test I tried for IsAdmin:

```
using System;
using MatanWebServer.Controllers;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table;

namespace UnitTestMatan
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UserControllerTests
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void IsAdmin_NotOnTheList_ReturnFalse()
        {
            var userController = new UserController();

            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("myconnectionstringthatidontwantyoutoknow");
            CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
            var result = UserController.IsAdmin(tableClient, "str");

            Assert.IsFalse(result);       
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to look into [moq](https://github.com/moq/moq4).

Answer (score 1):

This is more a followup to the answer given by "increddibelly" regarding using interfaces.

Let's take the following example:

I got a class called Person, which needs to send some information to a database. Then instead of having that logic inside the Person class I will have it in another class. This class is responsible for containing all the logic needed for the Person class to communicate with the database, such a class is often called a Data Access Layer (DAL) or repository. Okay, to the example:

The Person class:

```
public Person(IDALPerson d)
{
        dal = d;           
}

private IDALPerson dal;

public void SendOrder()
{            
    (Other logic...)
    dal.SendOrder("Bananas");
}
```

So here the Person class gets this DAL (dependency) from another place in the program through its contructor, this is a type of dependency injection. This DAL implements the interface IDALPerson, so the concrete DAL class could be:

```
public class PersonDAL : IDALPerson
{
    public void SendOrder()
    {
        (logic for adding order)
    }
}
```

And then when performing your tests you can create a mock object of IDALPerson and in that way while testing, your Person class does actually not use the database and then you can get some information by using the Moq framework as noted by "increddibelly" and thereby test the SendOrder function without relying on the database.
Your test could look like this:

```
    [Test]
    public void SendOrderTest()
    {
        //Arrange
        Mock<IDALPerson> MockDAL = new Mock<IDALPerson>();
        Person p = new Person(MockDAL);         

        //Act
        p.SendOrder();

        //Assert
        //Assert something.
   }
```

Comment: Thanks! I am still not sure how should I implement it into my code if I have to use a ClientTable type which is from Azure dll ?

Comment: I see, unfortunately I don't got a lot of knowledge about the stuff you are mentioning, just the generelt concept of the use of interfaces...

Answer (score 0):

For any and all unit tests ever (queue snowflake edge case), you'll want to replace the components that your code relies on with dummy / mock / fake objects.
There's an excellent library we use for that, Moq.

Say your code needs an

```
IStuffCreator
```

that has a

```
Stuff CreateStuff()
```

method, you can control the result of this external component as follows:

```
var sc = Mock<IStuffCreator>();
sc.Setup(x => x.CreateStuff()).Returns(new Stuff { Id = 1} );

MyClass classUnderTest = new classUnderTest(sc.Object);
```

any call to classUnderTest that touches the CreateStuff method will get a new Stuff with Id 1, because you set the fake component up that way.

and if you need azure to tell your code there's an Admin in the house, you can do the same thing.

```
var iauth = new Mock<IAzureAuthenticator>()
iauth.Setup(x => x.IsAdmin(It.IsAny<TableClient>, It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(true);
```

or if you only want to setup a specific case:

```
var myTableClient = new TableClient { Id = 123 };
iauth.Setup(x => x.IsAdmin(myTableClient, It.IsAny<string>)).Returns(true);
```

But then you will probably want to setup all other cases to return false so you're absolutely sure that your test value changes the behavior.

```
iauth.Setup(x => x.IsAdmin(It.IsAny<TableClient>(), It.IsAny<string>)).Returns(false);
iauth.Setup(x => x.IsAdmin(myTableClient, It.IsAny<string>)).Returns(true);
```

wish that it were this simple - but I'm sure you get the point.

If this doesn't work for you, it usually means you're not relying on interfaces but explicit implementations. Since it's a solid improvement (heh) to rely on interfaces instead of implementations, you now have a great opportunity to improve your code ;)

Comment: Thank you! now when I implement it into my test class, should it be something like:

    var sc = new Mock<UserController>();
    sc.Setup(x => x.IsAdmin(tableClient, "str")).Returns(false);

I kind of understand what you are saying but still dont know how to implement it on my test because IsAdmin gets a TableClient and a String, so how will I create a TableClient with content inside ?

Comment: for someone whose profile says they work at microsoft, that seems a very suspicious question. How about new TableClient { content = "inside" } ?
I'll update my answer, and if it works for you, maybe mark it as the answer that worked for you :)